# How to get hgetall results in spring redis executepiplelined as Map<byte[], byte[]>

Tags: java, redis

Is there any way, I can get List for hgetall requests when executed in pipeline using spring redis?

I am trying:

```
RedisCallback action = connection -> {
        evictDataItems.forEach(evictDataItem->connection.hGetAll(evictDataItem.getPrimaryKey()));
        return null;
    };
    List<Map<byte[],byte[]>> list = template.executePipelined(action);
```

The values of these Map needs to be passed to next request.

But, executePipelined itself converts it to string using JDK Serializer. 
So I get Map.
The bytes are my custom bytes which are created using multiple serializers.

So, please let me know if we have any option for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
List<Map<byte[],byte[]>> list = template.executePipelined(action, new BytesRedisSerializer());

public class BytesRedisSerializer implements RedisSerializer {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(Object t) throws SerializationException {
        return (byte[]) t;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws SerializationException {
        return bytes;
    }

}
```